# how to reshape the button android

Tags: android

I want to change my Button shape to an oval like button. please Help me

Comment: You might want to check your old questions and finally accept some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom 9-patch images as your button background. Then it can look anyway you want.

Two things you need:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Answer (score 0):

9-patch PNG's are kind of hard to stretch correctly when the image is oval. I'd recommend to take a look at [shape drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape).